# Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18209\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

i get bellow error when i call Invoke-Sqlcmd, see below full error log
PS>TerminatingError(Import-Module): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18209\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll' or one of its dependencies. Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"

> > TerminatingError(Import-Module): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18209\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll' or one of its dependencies. Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"
> > PS>TerminatingError(): "The 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' command was found in the module 'SqlServer', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module SqlServer'."
> > The 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' command was found in the module 'SqlServer', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module SqlServer'.
> > Invoke-Sqlcmd : The 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' command was found in the module 'SqlServer', but the module could not be loaded. Fo
> > r more information, run 'Import-Module SqlServer'.
> > At C:\ECC\DataImporter.ps1:17 char:1

- Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "EXEC dbo.Toshiba_ECC_Export" -ServerInstance "S ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Sqlcmd:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
  ```

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$dbcredential = Import-CliXml -Path "db.cred"
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\ECC\Logs\Log.txt" -Append

Write-Host "---------------ECC DATA IMPORTER------------------"
Write-Host "---------------------START---------------------"
Write-Host "---------------------Stopping old processes---------------------"

$CommandLines =  Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * from Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE '%eccimport%'"

foreach ($command in $CommandLines)
{
    Stop-Process -id $Command.processId -Force
}

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "EXEC dbo.Toshiba_ECC_Export" -ServerInstance "ServerXXXX" -Database "DatabaseXXX" -querytimeout 0 -Credential $dbcredential | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "Import_ECC.csv" -Encoding UTF8

$MyFile = Get-Content .\Import_ECC.csv
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines(".\Import_ECC_ENCODED.csv", $MyFile, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)

Start-Sleep -s 2

$destination = ".\Archive\Import_ECC_{0:d}.csv" -f (Get-Date)
Copy-Item ".\Import_ECC_ENCODED.csv" -Destination $destination

Start-Sleep -s 2
Write-Host "Import_ECC.csv was created."    
Write-Host $destination "was created."
Write-Host "Uploading to ECC". 
$test = java -jar ECCImport35.jar -o

Write-Host $test
Write-Host "----------------------END---------------------"
Write-Host "   "
Write-Host `
```

Comment: Did you run "Import-Module SqlServer" like exception said?  Make sure you run with Admin.  I suspect the cmdlet was loaded with Admin access and not normal user access.

Comment: the script is triggered using a scheduler,  if i trigger the script for the second or 3r time then it works and if again when triggred multiple time i get the error that i have posted, the scheduler used admin user to run this script and my user has admin access as well

Comment: I suspect there is a process that is running that needs to be terminated before you can successfully run the script.  Checking Task Manager may give clue.  I also found this : https://www.easy365manager.com/the-module-could-not-be-loaded/